# Evaluate $\int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin x}}{\sqrt[3]{\sin x} + \sqrt[3]{\cos x}} dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate 
>   $$\int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin^{1/3} x}{\sin^{1/3} x + \cos^{1/3} x} dx.$$

I tried doing by various methods but the answer is not coming.

Please help me out here. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me edit!...

Comment: Oh..thanks dear. Was trying to do but it was not fitting right.

Comment: Use $\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{f}\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x =
\int_{a}^{b}\mathrm{f}\left(a + b - x\right)\mathrm{d}x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$I=\int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin^{1/3} x}{\sin^{1/3} x + \cos^{1/3} x} dx\quad
\mbox{and}\quad
J=\int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\cos^{1/3} x}{\sin^{1/3} x + \cos^{1/3} x} dx.$$
Then we easily find that 
$I+J=\int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{\frac{\pi}{6}}1dx=\frac{\pi}{6}.$

Recalling that $\sin(\pi/2-x)=\cos(x)$ we have
$$J=\int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin^{1/3} (\pi/2-x)}{\cos^{1/3} (\pi/2-x) + \sin^{1/3} (\pi/2-x)} dx.$$
What do we obtain by letting $t=\pi/2-x$?

What is the value of $I$?

Comment: Ok. Give me some time to calculate I - J . Thanks for the hint .

Comment: @Sitanshu For $I-J$ consider the subtitution given in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks . Yes, J = I . That means 2I = π/6 . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sitanshu Perfect. Well done.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$I=\int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin^{1/3} x}{\sin^{1/3} x + \cos^{1/3} x} dx$$
let $x=\pi/2-u$, this should give you $2I = \pi/6$.

Comment: Why 2I since I1 and I2 are not the same as they differ by $$ sin^(1/3) x $$ and another Integral has in its numerator $$ cos^(1/3) x $$

Comment: I got it. Thanks.